# Recoil updating state when nothing has changed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, recoiljs

So I recently started using my API endpoints through recoil using `useRecoilStateLoadable`, it works great but the one issue I am having is on my data table, I want it to do another API call when a user selects for example page 2 or searches something, currently this is what my atom and selector looks like:

```
const entriesPerPage : EntriesPerPage = {defaultValue: 10};

export const filterScorecard = atom<ScorecardSearchRequest>({
    key: 'filterScorecard',
    default: {
        Draw: 2,
        PageNumber: 1,
        PageSize: entriesPerPage.defaultValue!,
        SortColumnNames: [],
        SortDirections: [],
        SearchValue: '',
        ConsolidationValues: null,
        IsGroupDataManagement: false,
        OnlySearchLockedScorecards: null,
        ScorecardEndDate: null,
        ScorecardTypes: ["43"],
        Usernames: null,
    }
})

export const allScorecardSelector = selector<ScorecardLicense>({
    key: 'allScorecardSelector',
    get: async ({get}) => {
        
        const filterScorecardData = get(filterScorecard);
        console.log(filterScorecard)
        try{
            const scorecardSearchResult = await BEEScorecardService.getUserScorecards(filterScorecardData);
            return scorecardSearchResult.data;
        }catch (error){
            console.error(error);
            return defaultObject;
        }
    }
})

export const allScorecardAtom = atom<ScorecardLicense>({
    key: 'allScorecardAtom',
    default: allScorecardSelector
})
```

I created the `filterScorecard` method to re trigger my API if state changes, and in my component, in the useEffect my code looks like this:

```
    const [entriesPerPage, setEntriesPerPage] = useState<EntriesPerPage>({ defaultValue: 10 });

    const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState<number>(1);
    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState<string>('');
    const [sortColumnNames, setSortColumnNames] = useState<string[]>([]);
    const [sortDirections, setSortDirections] = useState<SortDirections[]>([]);
    useEffect(() => {
            setFilterScorecard(prevState => ({
                ...prevState,
                pageNumber,
                entriesPerPage,
                searchValue,
                sortColumnNames,
                sortDirections
            }))
        }, [entriesPerPage, pageNumber, searchValue, sortColumnNames, sortDirections]);
```

But What I am noticing is that every time I navigate away and come back the API is getting triggered when its not supposed to be, if I remove the use effect and I navigate away and come back then the API doesnt load and it shows the correct data, but I am unable to search or go to the next page because of course the filterScorecard method isnt being called anymore. I am trying to figure out what I need to do in order for it not to do API calls if nothing in the state has changed.

**UPDATE**

I have Created a code Sandbox to show you the issue, if you click on about then it triggers the API, but if you click on home and about again it still triggers the API request and it should not be because nothing has changed in state. Only if I click Next page should it actually call the API again

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-monad-4l4gmq)

Comment: I'm not following what you mean by "updating state when nothing changed". What is special about the `useEffect` hook in the second snippet? What is `setFilterScorecard`? It *looks* like a `useState` updater function by name. Is the `useEffect` hook being called *more* than you think it should? What API calls are you referring to? Can you edit the post to include all relevant code you are working with and have an issue using? See [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean "every time you navigate away and come back"? Can you give an example?

Comment: @DrewReese I have added in a code sandbox with the issue I am having

Comment: @g0rb Ive added a code sandbox of the issue

Comment: From what I see of the code and the docs for [useRecoilStateLoadable](https://recoiljs.org/docs/api-reference/core/useRecoilStateLoadable/) it appears the code is doing what I'd expect. Navigate to `"/about"` and the `About` component mounts and runs the effect. Navigate back, `About` unmounts, navigate again to `"/about" and `About` mounts and runs the effect. I see the same behavior when clicking the next button, the effect runs. Admittedly though I'm unfamiliar with recoil. Are you saying that something should be cached, like the `getAllSelector` `fetch`'s GET request response value?

Comment: In other words, recoil appears to be a state management tool, not an API/services tool. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something here though.

Comment: @DrewReese Yes it is suppose to be caching the response, because that initial pageNumber is 1 on the `useEffect` and the `PaginateData` atom, it should only do a request if I select next page

Comment: I don't see anything that conditionally makes the GET request in the sandbox though, unless this is happening in the recoil code, outside your code. How many API requests are cached? What state updates are cached? This is starting to appear to not be an issue related to React hooks, but something more specific to understanding how recoil works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the API request is sent every time you navigate to the component is the async selector dependency is changing every time you mount the component.

> If any dependencies change, the selector will be re-evaluated and execute a new query.

https://recoiljs.org/docs/guides/asynchronous-data-queries#asynchronous-example

**What is a dependency of a selector?**

```
const selector = selector({
  key: "getAllSelector",
  get: async ({ get }) => {
    const filterScorecardData = get(filterScorecard);  <-- this is a dependency

    const res = await fetch(`https://my-api`);
  }
});
```

Every time your component mounts, you update the `filterScorecard` state.

```
...
useEffect(() => {
  setFilterScorecard(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    pageNumber,
    etc.,
  }));
```

Because you are updating the dependency state on every component mounting,
the `allScorecardSelector` selector will be re-evaluated and executed on every component mounting.

To prevent the API request from firing on ever component mount, you need to avoid updating the `filterScorecard` state on every component mount.

Comment: Do you know how I can achieve this to not trigger on every component mount?

Comment: You should try to move the `setFilterScorecard` from `useEffect` to UI handler callbacks i.e., an `onClick` callback. It's hard for me to tell you exactly what you know best how your app should function.